# Write to console without writing to redirected output

Tags: node.js

Is the only way to write to the console to use `console.warn()` or `console.error()` when output is redirected to a file (e.g., `node myscript.js > someFile.txt`)?  If there are other ways, I'd be interested.  It seems strange to use warn and error logs to send information to the console when redirection is being used.

Comment: Why do you want to output something to the console anyway? What's the context? *" It seems strange to use warn and error logs to send information to the console when redirection is being used."* Your script shouldn't care what is done with the output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/console.html#console_console) is worth taking a look into for the `Console` class.

One can actually define an object of `Console` class with parameters for stderr and stdout like so:

```
var Console = console.Console;
var output = fs.createWriteStream('./stdout.log');
var errorOutput = fs.createWriteStream('./stderr.log');

var logger = new Console(output, errorOutput);
//logger is the custom logger
```

In the above example, `logger.log()` logs to `./stdout.log` and `logger.error()` logs to `./stderr.log`.

Redirecting to standard output or standard can be done similarly. Standard output is identified by `process.stdout` and standard error by `process.stderr`.

Comment: I think `process.stdout` and `process.stderr` are more relevant here than `Console.`

Comment: What i was trying to say was that instead of redirecting to a file in the terminal, he's better off creating a custom logger, so it's easier to log to many different outputs.

Comment: Ah I see. I guess it depends on the purpose of the redirect.

Comment: I was hoping to avoid having to write to a file explicitly since this is a command-line utility but I may have to go down that route any way.  Thanks!

Comment: If it's going to be a command line utility, maybe you could pass the filename as an argument?

Comment: @kevin628 I forgot to tag you in the previous comment.